# JQuery Mobile Hiding Scrollbars After Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile for a client's website, and I have never used it before.  Unfortunately I cannot link the website, nor is it simple to just recreate the problem somewhere because it involved the library's AJAX transition system - in other words, it's spread across multiple pages.  I'm really hoping this is a known problem somebody can help me with though.

When I initialize a new page by navigating there through my address bar or refreshing, everything works fine.  When I transition there from within the site, scrolling is disabled.  Even if I apply overflow-y to the body, the html, the data-role="content" element, anything...it just doesn't work.  A scroll bar literally does not appear...if I inspect the elements in Chrome, I can see there are elements beneath the visible page that do have a detectable width and height, but even when every key element's overflow-y is set to scroll, the scrollbar is blank and unclickable.

Any help is **immensely** appreciated!

Comment: if you refresh after transition, does the same happen?

Comment: After refresh the page works fine.  I'd still love to figure this out, but for now I ended up ditching JQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-ajax="false"` in `<a>` tag to resolve this problem.